Black screen after installing nvidia drivers
I followed this guide to install nvidia drivers on kali linux.
https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/
after reboot, keep getting blank black screen also cannot switch to tty mode by pressing ctrl+alt+f1 to f6( none working)

can you SSH into the machine and check for errors? Perhaps your GPU is too old or too new to be supported by nvidia linux drivers?

It's rtx 2070 super and i think cannt ssh into the machine

i think cannt ssh into the machine well, first step is to determine that for sure
